# Free virtual scrolling over entire data set in Tabulator, when data are created server-side

Tags: tabulator

In my current project I am about to replace Datatables by Tabulator to render virtual tables with millions of rows backed by a database.

It is working in principle by using the progressive ajax loading and scroll mode features. So far so good

But from an user point of view it is must be possible to immediately scroll to the very last rows of the table.

With the given [example](http://tabulator.info/examples/4.1?#ajax-progressive) the next chunk of data will be loaded when the user scrolls to the end of table. What I want to achieve is a "free scrolling" within the virtual table, like in [Datatables](https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/examples/initialisation/server-side_processing.html).

Would that be possible with Tabulator too?
If so, what are the options/API to be used?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Im afraid this option currently isn't available as of tabulator 4.6

Comment: Is it now possible in Tabulator 4.9?

Comment: Nope im afraid not, this feature is not currently on the Tabulator roadmap. If you would like to see this added you would need to create a feature request on the [Tabulator GitHub Repo](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Suggested+Feature&template=feature_request.md&title=)